# C# .NET ReadFile from USB AccessViolationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, usb, dllimport, readfile

I am receiving an `AccessViolationException` when calling the ReadFile API.  I have looked at all of the entries on StackOverflow dealing with similar issues and have not had any success deciphering what is wrong.

Here is the relevant code in question:

**INVOKES**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename, UInt32 desiredaccess, UInt32 sharemode, IntPtr securityattributes, UInt32 creationdisposition, UInt32 flagsandattributes, IntPtr templatefile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, out byte[] lpbuffer, UInt32 nNumberofBytesToRead, out UInt32 lpNumberofBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte[] lpBuffer, UInt32 nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

**CREATE FILE FUNCTION CALL**

```
private IntPtr OpenPort(string port)
    {
        IntPtr printerhandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        printerhandle = CreateFile(port, 
                            (UInt32)(FileAccess.GENERIC_READ | FileAccess.GENERIC_WRITE), 
                            (UInt32)(FileShare.FILE_SHARE_READ | FileShare.FILE_SHARE_WRITE), 
                            IntPtr.Zero, 
                            (UInt32)FileMode.OPEN_EXISTING, 
                            (UInt32)(FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL), 
                            IntPtr.Zero);

        return (printerhandle);
    }
```

**READFILE FUNCTION CALL**

```
private bool WriteToPort(IntPtr printer, ref byte[] data)
    {
        bool success = true;
        byte[] data2 = new byte[64];
        byte[] dataread = new byte[64];
        int index = 0;
        int length = 64;
        uint written = 0;
        uint read = 0;

        while ((index + length) <= data.Length)
        {
            Array.Copy(data, index, data2, 0, length);
            success &= WriteFile(printer, data2, (uint)length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
            index += 64;
        }

        if ((index < data.Length) &&
            ((index + length) > data.Length))
        {
            length = data.Length - index;
            Array.Copy(data, index, data2, 0, length);
            success &= WriteFile(printer, data2, (uint)length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        success &= ReadFile(printer, out dataread, 64, out read, IntPtr.Zero);

        return success;
    }
```

The exception occurs when the `success &= ReadFile(printer, out dataread, 64, out read, IntPtr.Zero);` line is executed.

Here is the relevant stack trace as reported by VS2013:

```
StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.MngdNativeArrayMarshaler.ClearNative(IntPtr pMarshalState, IntPtr pNativeHome, Int32 cElements)
   at APP_NET.Main.ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, Byte[]& lpbuffer, UInt32 nNumberofBytesToRead, UInt32& lpNumberofBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped)
   at APP_NET.Main.WriteToPort(IntPtr printer, Byte[]& data) in Main.cs:line 770
```

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a wrong declaration of the `ReadFile` function. Remove `out` from the `lpbuffer` argument.

Import of the ReadFile:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, byte[] lpbuffer, UInt32 nNumberofBytesToRead, out UInt32 lpNumberofBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Reading a file:

```
success &= ReadFile(printer, dataread, 64, out read, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.  What keyed you in that that was the issue?  Also, I would give you an upvote, but my reputation is not quite there yet.

Comment: `out` for reference types means that memory will be allocated by callee and arrays are reference types. `ReadFile` doesn't allocate memory for the `lpbuffer`. It only copies bytes from a file to the buffer provided by you. Therefore, `out` keyword must not be used.