# USB C# .NET Write on USB printer device using kernel32.dll's WriteFile

Tags: c#, windows, usb, printers, kernel32

I've been trying to get it to work for a while, but I just can't. And looking online there don't seem to be many USB oriented answers for communicating with a printer.

The final objective is to communicate with the printer by USB, send information and receive data back. Using a [different application](https://www.lerup.com/printfile/) I was able to send the informaton as a binary file to the printer. Using Wireshark-usbcap I also sniffed the answer from the printer to see it does actually arrive and that the printer is able to respond to my queries via the USB connection.

I've looked at various resources, but some of the more useful ones were: ChatGPT and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774758/c-sharp-net-readfile-from-usb-accessviolationexception-was-unhandled) as it allowed to fix the code generated by ChatGPT and actually connect to the device.

Starting from this code provided by ChatGPT:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string fileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
    IntPtr securityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint flags,
    IntPtr template);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte[] lpBuffer,
    uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
    uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint nNumberOfBytesRead, [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string printerName = "YourPrinterName";
        string usbPort = "USB001"; // Replace with your port
        IntPtr printerHandle = CreateFile(usbPort, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (printerHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            byte[] dataToWrite = new byte[] { /* Your byte data */ };
            WriteToPrinter(printerHandle, dataToWrite);

            byte[] dataRead = ReadFromPrinter(printerHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to get printer handle.");
        }
    }

    public static void WriteToPrinter(IntPtr handle, byte[] data)
    {
        uint bytesWritten;
        System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped = new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped();
        WriteFile(handle, data, (uint)data.Length, out bytesWritten, ref lpOverlapped);
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFromPrinter(IntPtr handle)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; // Adjust the size as needed
        uint bytesRead;
        System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped = new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped();
        ReadFile(handle, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out bytesRead, ref lpOverlapped);
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, (int)bytesRead);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

After changing up the code, adding it into my application and testing different solutions, this is what I have right now:

```cs
public static class KernelPrinterWriter
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
        UInt32 desiredaccess, UInt32 sharemode, IntPtr securityattributes,
        UInt32 creationdisposition, UInt32 flagsandattributes, 
        IntPtr templatefile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint nNumberOfBytesRead, [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);



    public static bool WriteToPort(string port, ref byte[] data)
    {
        IntPtr hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool success = true;
        uint bytesWritten = 0;

        hPrinter = CreateFile(port,
                            (UInt32)(FileAccess.ReadWrite),
                            (UInt32)(FileShare.ReadWrite),
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            (UInt32)FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                            (UInt32)(FileAttribute.Normal),
                            IntPtr.Zero);

        System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped = new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped();
        success = WriteFile(hPrinter, data, (uint)data.Length, out bytesWritten, ref lpOverlapped);

        CloseHandle(hPrinter);

        return success && bytesWritten > 0;
    }
}
```

The parameters used inside the WriteToPort function are port: "USB001" and data is a small array of 4 bytes I'm sending to the printer to request for information.

Running this code I can see that bytesWritten ends up as 4 and success is true. But outside the application I am unable to see any reaction from the printer (the screen lights up whenever a command is received, but running this code nothing happens) and from wireshark-usbcap I can't see any outgoing packets, whereas I could see both outgoing and incoming packets using the PrintFile application.

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it the hard way? Is there a specific reason to not use the "usual" printer api?

Comment: By usual api are you talking about winspool.drv? Or something like libusb?
I did try them as well, but I couldn't come up with a working solution

Comment: Actually no. We are in C#. Look at some abstractions further up in the tree => [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is too high level likely. When I said I used PrintFile to send data to the printer those were binary files containing only the 4KB of data of the command that would trigger a response from the printer. If I can send information directly without needing a file that would be much better. Not only that, but I also need to read the response from the USB port that the printer will respond with. Something lower in that abstraction tree is what I need for this case

Comment: Ah, I see. So it _does_ matter that it is a _USB_ printer. Ok, if that's the case, then maybe use the [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)? It should be able to communicate to an emulated RS232 (which today is the default, I think). So basically you pretend you are communicating via serial port but you are actually talking to USB. Should _still_ be much less hassle than all of the above code in question and you can send and receive `byte[]`.

Comment: The communication must be via USB without simulating a COM device, the printer would have the option to do so, but the environment where it's going to be used it strictly requires USB instead. I did already develop modules to communicate using COM or LAN interfaces, but now I have to expand the application by including USB. The printer is capable of bidirectional comunication and I've tested that with the PrintFile and wireshark-usbcap as expained in the post. While we can change which library is used to get to that comunication, the fact that it has to be strictly usb can't be changed

Comment: Why not just use a `FileStream` with your handle? Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77052707/how-to-await-kernel32-readfile-or-set-a-timeout-in-c/77059421#77059421